# MvvmCross fluent binding for events (iOS). How i get parameters of event?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

How I can bind to event and set parameters to my ViewModel, using fluent binding type?

Example:

```
    set.Bind(SegmentControl).For("ValueChanged").To(vm => vm.SegmentControlValueChanged);

//--------- View Model:

   public MvxAsyncCommand<object> SegmentControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxAsyncCommand<object>(async obj =>
            {
               //obj alwais is null
               return;
            });
        }
    }
```

How I can get a sender or other parameters (eg EventArgs) ?

How need use MvxAsyncCommand and when ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding `CommandParamter` after `To`:

```
   set.Bind(SegmentControl).For("ValueChanged").To(vm => vm.SegmentControlValueChanged).CommandParameter(param);
```

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/8a824c797747f74716fc64c2fd0e8765c29b16ab/MvvmCross/Core/Binding/BindingContext/MvxFluentBindingDescription.cs